# PHP/mySQL prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

Is the below php code vulnerable to SQL injection, or is it sufficiently secure as written?  Also:

1. Should I apply `mysql_real_escape_string()` to the values passed by the user (or attempt to neuter them in any other way)...?
2. Should I be using `php_flag magic_quotes off`...?
3. Should I be using `php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0`...?

   ```
   $mysqli = new mysqli($server_name, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username=? AND password=?";

   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password)) {
   $stmt->execute();
   ```

Comment: **As safe as it gets.** Think of prepared statements as internally escaping the data. They're actually shipping it binary back to server...

Comment: Magic quotes should be off, but they default that way in PHP 5.3, and have been removed in PHP5.4+

Answer (score 0):

Because the query is being prepared SQL injection is impossible. But this doesn't mean that prepared statement are 100% safe.
Personally I prefer PDO. Just have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is perfectly safe, but since you are using Mysqli and you did prepare it, it should be fine